# Error with mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to blind my MySql query I noob in this, I want prevent to SQL Injection on my query. This is my statement but have one error

```
$sql = $conn ->prepare("SELECT * FROM Personas WHERE concat(nombre1,' ',apellido1) LIKE '% :name %'");
    $sql-> bind_param('name', $q);
```

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match
>   number of parameters in prepared statement in

this work fine but that is a bad way

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Personas WHERE concat(nombre1,' ',apellido1) LIKE '%".$q."%';
```

Please help me with this and what other way Can I use to protect my query in my PHP Code

**Thank you for all, that was my solution**

```
$sql = $conn ->prepare('SELECT * FROM Personas WHERE concat(nombre1," ",apellido1) LIKE  ? ');
    $key = "%".$q."%";
    $sql-> bind_param('s', $key);
```

Comment: This statement in phpmyadmin work fine       SELECT * FROM Personas WHERE concat(nombre1,' ',apellido1) LIKE '%jo%'

Answer (score 0):

Use bind_param this way:

```
$sql= $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Personas WHERE concat(nombre1,' ',apellido1) LIKE :name");
$q= "%$q%";
$sql->bindParam(':name', $q);
$sql->execute();
```

Comment: Now I have this error Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in *** this is the edited code ***  $sql = $conn ->prepare("SELECT * FROM Personas WHERE concat(nombre1,' ',apellido1) LIKE :name");
 
 $sql-> bind_param('name', '%'.$q.'%');

Comment: `$sql->bindParam(':name', $q);` not bind_param

Comment: shon that Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bindParam()

Comment: Tried `$q= "%$q%"; $sql-> bind_param('s', $q);`?

Comment: Yes Sr, and nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

The [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli-stmt.bind-param.html) uses question marks (?) to indicate where a subsequent bind_param value should be placed.  Try replacing ":name" with the a "?" in the query and your bind_param should follow the syntax bind_param("s", $q) where "s" is a string identifying the types of values being bound: s for string, d for decimal, i for integer, etc.